# Stall on low airspeed with high power on right-turning propeller

Tags: propeller, stall, principles-of-flight

Q: The pilot of an aeroplane with a single engine and right-turning propeller (clockwise from the pilot’s viewpoint) decides to go around. The pilot raises the nose too much as the power increases and stalls the aircraft. Most probably, the aircraft will…

A: Enter an incipient spin to the left due to roll and yaw caused by the propeller.

I understand why aircraft will roll and yaw to the left; it is due to propeller effects, but how rolling and yawing to the left helps developing a spin to the left? One thing that comes to my mind is when yawing left, airflow on the right wing is higher then on the left wing so left wing is more stalled then right and this couses aircraft to spin left. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. How do you enter a spin? By bringing the plane to a stall and stomping rudder as the stall is starting to break. Left rudder, right wing speeds up slightly, so AOA is reduced slightly, left wing vice versa, so as the stall breaks, left wing is more deeply stalled than the right, and the spin to the left starts as the not quite fully stalled right wing wants to drive (glide) forward.

Here in Canada, spins are taught in flight training, so the effects of yaw at spin entry becomes pretty obvious to the student in short order.